# Prevent URL address bar and prevent refreshing page using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to prevent refreshing page after page completely load. And prevent user to change URL address bar value manually. And do not refresh page, If page will refresh then session will reset automatically.

Comment: It's not possible for JavaScript to restrict access to the URL bar and refreshing the page. Also note that refreshing the page does not affect the session.

Comment: Sir, I am trying to use e.preventDefault;   jquery method but its ask stay or leave and after refresh page.

Comment: Maybe stop them closing the browser?  What about stopping them pulling the plug on their PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to prevent some changes to url look into javascript popup window you can define what size the window should open  and then
when the popup loads your view you can prevent prevent refresh in that view